# Guest Wi-Fi not getting proper IP's

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I have a main router and a cable modem router. The cable modem router(NETGEAR C3000) acts as Wireless Access Point with DHCP disabled bridge mode.

Main router IP is 192.168.0.1 sm: 255.255.192.0 gateway:192.168.0.1
For my WAP IP adress is 192.168.0.2. My WAP has two SSIDs one for the private and one for the guest.

I can browse the net when connecting to private, but when I switch to guest it says limited access, and gave me an ip of 192.168.1.x 255.255.255.0 and gateway:192.168.1.1. What is the meaning of this? What I know is that the NETGEAR cable modem router that acts as my WAP states that: 192.168.1.x to 192.168.7.x are reserved for Guest Network? How can I fix this? I already disable the DHCP of my NETGEAR WAP but nothing works. Only the private wifi is accessible.

[Here is the layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHHep.png)

Comment: "Guess"? I guess you meant to say "Guest"?

Comment: Change your gateway IP to 192.168.0.1 on the WAP. Delete the LAN gateway setting on the main router.

Answer (score 2):

That's the whole purpose of a guest net. You get an IP from another subnet, so your guest net (192.168.1.0) can not access your main net (192.168.0.0) but browse the internet.

Comment: how can I fix this one? the guest net cant access the internet.

Comment: Post screenshots and schematic layout, provide more informations. Has it worked in the past? Post the output of `ipconfig` when connected to both nets etc..

Comment: View the picture above. when i'm in private wifi ipconfig is this : e.g 192.168.0.x 255.255.192.0 192.168.0.1 and when I'm connected to guest wifi : ip : e.g 192.168.1.4 255.255.255.0 gateway: 192.168.1.1

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. Private and guest net are in different subnets. There is nothing to fix from this point of view. You say you can't access the internet when connected with the guest net. This problem has nothing to do with the IP address ranges in the first place, so we need more info to help you out.

Comment: what kind of info?

Comment: Your gateway settings are wrong on both routers.

Comment: Read the second comment to this answer.